# Jquery Migrate Not Working Properly for Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, migration

Here is my jQuery library for my web page:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

Here is my click handler jQuery script:

```
(function($) {
    $('#all').click(function(e) {
        alert('Success');
    });
})(jQuery);
```

How can I execute my click function without changing my jQuery library.

Comment: what do you mean by "without changing my jquery library" ?

Comment: i mean without changing these two jquery library.                 <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>

Comment: The jQuery library is irrelevant to your click handler, so I'm unclear what you mean.

Comment: Without changing them into what?

Comment: how can in implement click function on this                                    (function($) {    ..click function here .. })(jQuery);

Answer (score 0):

**Finally i got an way to fix it**

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

Under these two jquery library i have to add this library

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

and then i have to call  *non-conflict*  like this below *code*

```
<script>
    var nuc= $.noConflict(); //i am giving name nuc for the noconflict variable, you can give what ever you want.  
    nuc(document).ready(function(){
        nuc('#input').click(function(){
           alert('success');
        });
    });
</script>
```

**i test it several times, it's working fine.**